# Erro de SSL com file_get_contents

Tags: php, ssl, file-get-contents

Quando tento abrir uma url através do `file_get_contents`, estou tendo problemas quando a página é `https`. Não falo de páginas externas, mas em algumas bibliotecas onde as imagens da própria aplicação é aberta pelo `file_get_contents`, se tiver `https`, gera o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL

routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /caminho/public/test.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents():
Failed to enable crypto in /caminho/public/test.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(http://meusite.com.br): 
failed to open stream: operation failed in /caminho/public/test.php on line 4
```

É claro, eu sei que é possível resolver isso usando o `stream_context_create`, mas eu não quero essa solução. Eu uso biblioteca na minha aplicação que usa o `file_get_contents` (o DOMPDF)` e é um absurdo pensar em editar o código-fonte, uma vez que se eu tiver que fazer uma atualização na biblioteca, teria que fazer o "remendo" toda hora.

Gostaria de entender o que é que gera esse erro. Esse problema começou desde que migramos da antiga hospedagem. Atualmente a Amazon hoje e a configuração foi feita por nós. Pedimos as chaves do certificado de cada um dos domínios e configuramos.

Gostaria de saber se o erro indica algum tipo de erro na configuração do nosso SSL, pois quando faço um `file_get_contents` para as urls do *Google*, por exemplo, funciona tudo normalmente.

Outro ponto importante é que o SSL funciona normalmente no navegador, porém está dando apenas com `file_get_contents`.

É possível fazer a verificação [nessa](https://cardvantagens.com.br/) url.

**Nota**: Por favor, não respondam nada relativo a "desabilitar" a verificação do SSL nas requisições, pois não quero criar outro problema (nada de "soluções temporárias definitivas"). Quero entender o que está ocorrendo e resolver.

Comment: Enquanto SSL por falta autenticação é obrigatório. Você pode diferente para heroku tem PHP

Comment: veja se [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more) e [essa wiki php](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tls-peer-verification) te ajuda.

Comment: O PHP tem uma [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/context.ssl.php) para isso.

Comment: Tente **OpenSSL** (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.openssl.php) ou **nginx** pode ajudar tb

Answer (score 4):

Agradeço ao meu amigo @GuilhermeNascimento pela resposta e pelo @Bacco ter ajudado no chat a resolver o problema.

Finalmente consegui resolver!

Vamos aos passos necessários. Eu estou usando a versão 5.6 do PHP.

Depois de ter feita todas as configurações necessárias no apache, é necessário fazer uma configuração para o PHP.

Primeiro, precisamos localizar qual é a localização do arquivo de certificado que o PHP está lendo. Pode ser visto através da função `openssl_get_cert_locations`.

No meu caso, ela retornou o seguinte:

```
[
 "default_cert_file" => "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem",
 "default_cert_file_env" => "SSL_CERT_FILE",
 "default_cert_dir" => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs",
 "default_cert_dir_env" => "SSL_CERT_DIR",
 "default_private_dir" => "/usr/lib/ssl/private",
 "default_default_cert_area" => "/usr/lib/ssl",
 "ini_cafile" => "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem",
 "ini_capath" => "",
]
```

Observando o valor de `default_cert_file`, você agora sabe de onde o PHP lê os [cerificados intermediários](https://br.godaddy.com/help/o-que-e-um-certificado-intermediario-868).

Explicando de maneira bem rápida, o arquivo `cert.pem` contém uma lista de certificados confiáveis de cada Autoridade Certificadora. Ele é chamado de [CA Bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).

Você deve baixá-lo nesse [link](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) e o mover para a localização retornada em `default_cert_file`. Ou então você pode baixá-lo para uma outra localização e definir, através do `php.ini`, a localização do seu arquivo através da diretiva `openssl.cafile`.

```
openssl.cafile = /caminho/do/cacert.pem
```

Toda vez que você fizer uma requisição pelo PHP via `curl` ou qualquer outra função usando o `wrapper https`, usando a opção `verify_peer`, o PHP vai ler esse arquivo para saber quais são as Autoridade Certificadora válidas.

Depois dessas operações, caso ainda o erro demonstrado na pergunta permaneça, você deve adicionar manualmente, ao final do arquivo, o código intermediário do seu certificado SSL.

O usuário @Bacco me recomendou acessar pelo próprio navegador e baixar esse código.

Veja a imagem:

[image: Baixando o certificado]

No meu caso, escolhi a opção `Rapid SSL SHA256 CA` e exportei os dados. Dá pra fazer isso em qualquer navegador. O nome vai mudar de acordo com a sua Autoridade Certificadora.

> ### Importante
>
> A partir do momento em que você está adicionando uma nova CA no seu sistema,
>   você está dizendo que confia "cegamente" naquela entidade, portanto, só faça
>   isso se **realmente** se tratar de um certificado que você tenha certeza
>   absoluta da origem e idoneidade.

**Nota**: Você também pode encontrar o código no site Provedor do serviço SSL, mas no meu caso funcionou melhor baixando do navegador.

O código que você vai baixar do certificado, será algo parecido com isso:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Após disso, edite o arquivo marcado como `default_cert_file` no seu PHP. No meu caso, eu renomeei para `cert.pem` depois do download. Agora, adicione o código do certificado que você baixou do navegador (ou o certificado da CA que você está usando) e adicione no arquivo anteriormente citado. É recomendável você colocar no final do seu.

Após isso talvez seja necessário reiniciar o Apache, mas no meu caso, não precisou.

Link do CA Bundle:

https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Importante mencionar que se você adicionar um certificado de uma entidade duvidosa, está quebrando toda a segurança do SSL. Tem que ter muita certeza do que está fazendo para adicionar uma CA nova num sistema.

Comment: @Bacco pode adicionar isso à resposta. Realmente, eu sou uma negação em SSL :D

Comment: Fiz um adendo escandaloso, formate como achar que deve :P

Comment: O adendo precisou ser escandaloso, pois ele põe em risco usuários que não saberiam o que estão fazendo,

Answer (score 2):

Posso estar enganado, mas conforme as respostas aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/1518921 você deve baixar o http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem (se bem que tenho certeza que se instalar o SSL no seu servidor já haverá este arquivo) e definir o stream assim:

```
$url = 'https://site';

$streamSSL = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true
    )
));

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $streamSSL);
```

### PHP 5.6

No php5.6 é possivel configurar o openssl via php.ini (http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php):

> openssl.cafile "" PHP_INI_PERDIR  Disponível desde PHP 5.6.0
>
> openssl.capath "" PHP_INI_PERDIR  Disponível desde PHP 5.6.0

Exemplo:

```
openssl.cafile=/path/cacert.pem
```

Assim acredito que seja possível configurar o caminho. Já sobre o `capath` se não especificado ele irá procurar um adequado, então acho que talvez seja possivel usar diretamente o file_get_contents:

```
$url = 'https://site';

$response = file_get_contents($url, false);
```

### CURL

Como citei, acredito que se o SSL (openssl) estiver instalado ele deva funcionar sem precisar de configurações, no curl também é assim mas é disponivel desde o Disponível desde o PHP 5.3.7 no php.ini usando `curl.cainfo = /path/cacert.pem`:

```
$url = 'https://site';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

> **Nota:** O caminho do certificado deve ser absoluto

### Instalar ssl

Acredito que a única coisa que seja necessário configurar seja o openssl habilitando a extensão pra ele, se for Windows e distros baseados em debian (repositório) é só remover comentário (`;extension=`) na seguinte linha:

```
extension=openssl.so
```

ou (windows):

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Todavia se você mesmo compilou o PHP (usando `make` por exemplo, será necessário recompilar) usando o parametro `--with-openssl[=DIR]` (http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php)

Sendo Debian/ubuntu/etc instale o libssl (se não estiver instalado):

- Debian:

  ```
  su
  apt-get install libssl1.0.0
  ```
- Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
  ```

Comment: A única parte que tá ruim na sua resposta é que eu teria que definir no `file_get_contents`. A library é quem faz a consulta, então não dá pra mudar. Teria como fazer pelo PHP.INI? (To quebrando a cabeça aqui)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não sei informar, mas entendi a sua necessidade você deve estar usando uma biblioteca pronta, geralmente quando temos o openssl instalado acho que pelo CURL funciona sem precisar de muita configuração, vou editar a resposta, acho que deve ter sim pelo php.ini

Comment: Eu preciso entender o que acontece, quando faço pela minha aplicação local, ocorre o mesmo erro.