# Problema no DOMDocument OpenSSL

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler, crawling

Estou tentando pegar uma informação em um site usando `DOMDocument` mas esta dando um erro.

```
DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed    



 $html = new DOMDocument();
 $html->loadHTMLFile("https://sistemasweb.sefaz.ba.gov.br/sistemas/DTE/Contribuinte/SSL/ASLibrary/Login");
 $dado = $html->getElementsByTagName('__EVENTVALIDATION');
 echo $dado;
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o certificado do endereço https://sistemasweb.sefaz.ba.gov.br/sistemas/DTE/Contribuinte/SSL/ASLibrary/Login, ele é invalido, mas também pode ocorrer, mesmo que corrijam o site, do seu PHP não ter os certificados configurados, para o futuro acaso tente isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137009/3635, que ficaria:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true
    )
));

libxml_set_streams_context($context);
```

Ou configurar o php.ini adequadamente:

```
openssl.cafile=/path/cacert.pem
```

E reiniciar o Apache ou Nginx. No entanto é como disse, as soluções acima não vão funcionar, são para quando o site que você esta tentando acessar estiver com o certificado corrigido, por enquanto você pode desabilitar a checagem do SSL assim:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
));

libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTMLFile("https://sistemasweb.sefaz.ba.gov.br/sistemas/DTE/Contribuinte/SSL/ASLibrary/Login");
$dado = $html->getElementsByTagName('__EVENTVALIDATION');

echo $dado;
```

Se eventualmente o `libxml_set_streams_context` não funcionar pode experimentar mudar a abordagem para:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    )
));

$conteudosite = file_get_contents("https://sistemasweb.sefaz.ba.gov.br/sistemas/DTE/Contribuinte/SSL/ASLibrary/Login", false, $context);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($conteudosite);

$dado = $html->getElementsByTagName('__EVENTVALIDATION');

echo $dado;
```

Comment: O certificado é válido, mas a autoridade certificadora que o emitiu não é reconhecida (a chave corresponde ao certificado, mas a _verificação_ na lista de autoridades reconhecidas falhou). São coisas bem diferentes. A resposta merece um pequeno ajuste nesse sentido.