# Retornar JSON consulta POST PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho esse script em PHP, porém não consigo visualizar o resultado do POST
[Body]. Ele envia uma consulta de CPF e deveria retornar um json com os dados. Mas não aparece nada na consulta.

```
<?php 
$array = '{ 
    "cpf_cnpj": "83899526000182"
}'; 

$json = json_encode($array);
$ch = curl_init('http://mobi.ieptb.org.br/consulta');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    'Content-Type: application/json',

    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))

);


$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

?>
```

Ele deveria retornar o seguinte JSON (DADOS QUE EU QUERO OBTER):

```
[
{
"uf": "SC",
"codigo_cartorio": 1,
"codigo_cidade": 4205407,
"descricao": "2º TABELIONATO DE NOTAS E 1º PROTESTO DE TÍTULOS",
"endereco": "Rua Tenente Silveira, 221 , Centro - Florianópolis - SC - Telefone: 4830391991",
"telefone": "4830391991",
"data_atualizacao": "16/10/2019",
"quant_protestos": 1,
"protestos":[
{
"data_protesto": "15/05/2018",
"valor_protestado": "R$88.545,00",
"valor_protestado_o": 88545
}
]
},
```

[image: IMAGEM DO TALEND API TESTER COM O RETORNO]

Comment: Qual o valor de `$jsonRet` no final?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o retorno. Eu mando uma requisição via POST com o json contendo cpf_cnpj e gostaria que me retornasse os dados acima da pergunta.

Comment: E o que ele de fato retorna?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Confesso que sou iniciante na área. Mas explicando em geral: Preciso enviar um CPF via POST para http://mobi.ieptb.org.br/consulta. O response da requisição é o Json acima na pergunta. Queria ler esses dados (uf, codigo_cartorio, data_protesto e etc.)

Comment: `var_dump($jsonRet); exit` adicione isso no seu código, no final, e coloque qual foi a saída gerada.

Comment: Cara, você testou a URL? Ta retornando erro 500 do servidor. Nunca vai receber nada.

Comment: O retorno foi NULL. Porém, no Talend que é um testador de API ele está retornando normal; Coloquei o print na pergunta

Comment: Guilherme [o problema esta no que passou no json_encode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416928/3635) cc @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você criou isto que é uma string:

```
$array = '{ 
    "cpf_cnpj": "83899526000182"
}';
```

E tentou aplicar json_encode:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Ou seja isto **não** vai para o curl assim:

```
{ 
    "cpf_cnpj": "83899526000182"
}
```

Vai assim:

```
"{ \n    \"cpf_cnpj\": \"83899526000182\"\n}"
```

isto porque simplesmente você quer que uma string vire json, o que não tem sentido, bastaria passar a string direto, já que ela já tem o formato de json:

```
<?php 
$json = '{ 
    "cpf_cnpj": "83899526000182"
}'; 

$ch = curl_init('http://mobi.ieptb.org.br/consulta');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    'Content-Type: application/json',

    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))

);


$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Ou então se deseja usar um array para manipular o valor de cpf_cnpj antes de enviar, basta usar um array mesmo, exemplo se viesse de um POST:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['cpfCnpj'])) die('informe o cpf');

$array = array( 
    "cpf_cnpj" => $_POST['cpfCnpj']
);

$json = json_encode($array);

$ch = curl_init('http://mobi.ieptb.org.br/consulta');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

    'Content-Type: application/json',

    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))

);

$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Outra possibilidade é do servidor de destino estar direcionando para HTTPS, ou seja  o seu PHP não está configurado no php.ini para conexões seguras, para fazer isto siga as dicas destas respostas:

- [Erro de SSL com file_get_contents](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136998/3635)

Que é basicamente habilitar o openssl no php.ini e configurar o certificado no php.ini mais ou menos assim:

```
curl.cainfo = /caminho/cacert.pem
```

Você pode baixar o certificado em: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Caso não consiga ou esteja desenvolvendo algo rápido é desligar a checagem de segurança assim:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Claro que isto deixará os dados expostos para interceptadores no meio do caminho, então assim que possível configure o SSL no curl, se a sua hospedagem estiver com este problema então solicite ao helpdesk dela para habilitar a segurança (mas creio que seja improvável uma hospedagem sem isto)

Comment: Entendo. Ma o retorno ainda é NULL. Realizei o teste no Talend (testador de API) e o mesmo retornou a consulta normalmente (coloquei o print na pergunta)

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte testei aqui no meu PC e funcionou perfeitamente veja o teste: https://repl.it/@GuilhermeNasci5/PHP-cURL

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte esse site mobi.ieptb.org.br está instável, tem hora que não abre nem pelo Talend, postman, etc. Aqui tem hora que vai e tem hora que não funciona.

Comment: Passou hoje por uma instabilidade, mas aparentemente já retornou ao normal

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte blz, testei agora, veja funcionou normalmente:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X99E.png, algo mais que você precise? Esta funcionando ai?

Comment: Coloquei o seu código no meu htdocs. O retorno é sempre bool(false). Pelo postman e talend as requisições estão ok

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte depois de `$jsonRet = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));` adicione isto `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` e pega o resultado me envia aqui.

Comment: string(34) "Recv failure: Connection was reset"

Comment: Usando o codigo do link https://repl.it/@GuilhermeNasci5/PHP-cURL, o resultado é bool(false)

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte pode ser firewall, mas faça o seguinte teste, adicione isto após o curl_init: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`, se funcionar é porque o site esta redirecionando para HTTPS, e o teu php não esta configurado com OPENSSL

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: @GuilhermeDuarte por favor marque a resposta como correta, grato!

Answer (score 0):

Tenho um método mais simples com file_get_contents. Faça um teste aí.

```
<?php

    $url = 'http://mobi.ieptb.org.br/consulta';

    $body = '{"cpf_cnpj": "83899526000182"}';

    $opts = [
        'http' =>
            [
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n". 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body),
            'content' => $body,
            'timeout' => 60
        ]
    ];
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $a = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
    echo '<pre>' ;
    print_r(json_decode($a));
```

Saída esperada

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [uf] => SC
            [codigo_cartorio] => 1
            [codigo_cidade] => 4205407
            [descricao] => 2┬║ TABELIONATO DE NOTAS E 1┬║ PROTESTO DE T├ìTULOS
            [endereco] => Rua Tenente Silveira, 221 , Centro - Florian├│polis - SC - Telefone: 4830391991
            [telefone] => 4830391991
            [data_atualizacao] => 16/10/2019
            [quant_protestos] => 1
            [protestos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [data_protesto] => 15/05/2018
                            [valor_protestado] => R$88.545,00
                            [valor_protestado_o] => 88545
                        )

                )

        )
......
```